# Error else without if

Tags: java, if-statement

I don't know if im using the conditinal statement (if and else) correctly.
It says Kuiz.java:29: error: 'else' without 'if'
and the same at line 40

```
    System.out.println("Fillojme me kuizin");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("P1) Cili eshte kryeqyteti i Frances? \t\n 1)Londra \t\n 2)Parisi \t\n 3)Roma");
    int a = scan.Int();

    if(a == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("E sakte! ");
        }
    else 
        {
            System.out.println("E pasakte, Parisi eshte pergjigja e sakte");
        }

    System.out.println("P2)A mund te ruajme vleren \"dera\" ne nje variabel te tipit int? \t\n 1)Po \t\n 2)Jo");
    int b = scan.nextInt();
    if(b == 2 );
        {
            System.out.println("E Sakte!");
        }
    else
        {
            System.out.println("E pasakte, dera eshte nje String kurse ne variabel mund te ruajme vetem numra te plote");
        }

    System.out.println("P3)Cili eshte rezultati i 6+9/3 \t\n 1)5 \t\n 2)5 \t\n 3)15/3");
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    if(c == 2);
        {
            System.out.println("E sakte!");
        }
    else    
        {
            System.out.println("Pergjigja e pasakte");

        }
}
```

}

Comment: if(b == 2 ); note this

Comment: Vote to close as this is little more than a trivial typo and not likely to help future visitors.

Comment: The one error that everyone does when they start out coding.

Comment: Yeah Im new to coding soo... Mistakes like this happen once in a while

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is a very common error, though. There are lots of people who make it, so it certainly will be useful to others. It was once even the basis of a bug report to Sun...

Comment: @chiastic-security: nah, there are many many copies of this same question on this site, and it didn't help the OP and is not likely going to help future visitors. Just delete this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Except it did help the OP..  I agree it's trivial, and I'm sure it's a duplicate. But we all start somewhere and asking questions regarding their code is kind of what this site is for.

Comment: Does anyone know how to count the correct answers ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the semicolons after your `if` conditions.

The syntax is

```
if (condition)
{
  do something
} else {
  do something else
}
```

If you add a semicolon then it means

```
if (condition)
    ;  // i.e. do nothing

{
  do something // this is divorced from the if statement
}

else // this is an error because it's not linked with an if statement
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found some other problems too, Its good now